# Hide dragged element from it`s previous location while dragging it

Tags: css, angular, sass, drag-and-drop, primeng

I'm using DragDropModule from `primeng` 8.1.1 in Angular project version 8.2.

The problem is that I`m trying to hide the placed element when I\'m dragging it from one location to another in a container. And by that to show the element only in the new place where it`s gonna be dropped before it`s dropped.

[image]

I tried to change the display and opacity properties of the placed element with `ngStyle` while I'm dragging it. 
 But using `display: none;` I cannot move the element or using `opacity: 0;` I cannot see the dragged element and only the cursor is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this scss might help solve your problem. You may need to include it globally if you are trying to do this within a cdk overlay:

```
.cdk-drag {
  &.cdk-drag-preview > *{
    cursor: move;
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  }

  &.cdk-drag-placeholder > *{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```